# Paragraphs not in place

Tags: html, css

I want the paragraphs to go under the image, not over it.
I also want bar to be at the bottom, and stick there like a nav bar does.

I've already added these properties to the bar:

- postition: absolute
- bottom: 0

And on the pages without paragraphs it was at the bottom.

It seems like this problem should be easily fixed, but I have no clue why this is happening.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Wandel door de kattekampen met verhalen"
    />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Boom 1945</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="main-head">
      <nav>
        <div class="home">
          <a href="../../index.html"><h1>Home</h1></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="links">
          <li><a href="../audio/">Audio</a></li>
          <li><a href="../tekst/">Tekst</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="hero-fragment">
      <div class="hero-tekst">
        <h2>Boom 1945</h2>
        <h3>Reigerstraat / Pauwstraat</h3>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="plattegrond">
      <img
        src="../../Files/img/wijk-website/overige/7853c6b3-7ae8-4735-99b7-00ba028254b8.JPG"
        alt="plattegrond"
      />
    </section>
    <section class="fragment-tekst">
      <div class="tekst">
        <p>
          Op 2 juni 1945 werd de bevrijdingsboom op het pleintje
          Pauwstraat/Reigerstraat geplant. Deze boom is geplant door de heer
          Brits, oud-politieman en op dat moment de oudste bewoner van de
          Kattekampen. Bij de feestelijke bijeenkomst was een Canadese militaire
          band aanwezig met pipes en drums, gekleed in traditioneel Schots
          tenue. De indringende tonen van de doedelzakken pasten natuurlijk goed
          bij deze bijzondere gebeurtenis. Volgens zeggen zou toen in de grond
          onder de boom een koker mee begraven zijn met daarin een oorkonde..
        </p>
        <p>
          DAGBOEK FRAGMENT Zaterdag 2 juni 1945 <br />
          We hadden de Engelse, Amerikaanse en Russische vlag en natuurlijk ook
          de Nederlandse vlag aan het pleintje hangen. Mijnheer de Haas had
          prinses Juliana en prins Bernhard, en daar hebben we een oranje roes
          omheen gedaan, en die stonden bij Buiten op het platje. Gistermiddag
          werd de koningin er ook tussen gezet. Om 2 uur is het begonnen. Er zou
          in het pleintje een herdenkingsboom geplant worden, door de oudste
          buurtbewoners, n.l. mijnheer Brits en mijnheer van Putten. Die twee
          zouden hem gistermiddag bij de opening planten, maar de voorzitter en
          Hendrik hebben het gistermorgen al gedaan, omdat het de tijd van het
          jaar niet was om een Amerikaanse eik te planten en dan ’s middags
          helemaal niet. De planting van de boom zou geschieden met een
          oorkonde. Die oorkonde was zo mooi, gewoon zonde dat die de grond in
          moest. De voorzitter sprak het openingswoord, en toen mocht mijnheer
          Brits de oorkonde in de grond stoppen, en mijnheer van Putten mocht
          het gat dichtgooien. Toen het klaar was, werd er een rondedans om de
          vrijheidsboom gedaan. Daarna begonnen de spelen.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="fragment-bar">
      <div class="bar">
        <a href="../tekst/introductie.html"
          ><img src="../../Files/icons/back-button.svg" alt="back"
        /></a>
        <a href="../tekst/boom-2019.html"
          ><img src="../../Files/icons/forward-button.svg" alt="forward"
        /></a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.main-head {
  background: #262628;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.home {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
      -ms-flex: 2 1 40rem;
          flex: 2 1 40rem;
}

.links {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 40rem;
          flex: 1 1 40rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
}

.links a {
  color: #ebd728;
}

.hero-fragment {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), to(transparent)), url("../Files/img/wijk-foto 1.png");
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), transparent), url("../Files/img/wijk-foto 1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 25vh;
  color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero-tekst h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.plattegrond {
  height: 20vh;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}

.plattegrond img {
  width: 40vh;
  text-align: center;
}


.fragment-tekst {
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.fragment-tekst p {
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
  width: 80%;
}

.tekst {
  width: 80%;
}

.fragment-bar {
  background: #262628;
  height: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.bar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}






Thanks in advance
```

Comment: External links tend to break and nuke value for future visitors to this question. Instead, opt to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) **in the body of your question**.

Comment: Dude, so much code. Who is going to read and work on all this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem with paragraphs and image. But for the problem with the nav bar, here is the solution

```
.fragment-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
```

You just need to change absolute with fixed